# Dimension of $\mathrm{Hom}_G(V, W)$ in terms of characteristic polynomial

Tags: gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory

$\DeclareMathOperator\Hom{Hom}$Let $G$ be a (pro-)cyclic group (topologically) generated by $\phi$, and let $V,W$ be two finite-dimensional (continuous) $k$-linear semisimple representations of $G$, where $k$ is some algebraically closed (complete) field.

Let $$P_V(t) = \prod_{i=1}^n (t - a_i), P_W(t) = \prod_{j=1}^m (t - b_j)$$
be the characteristic polynomials of $\rho_V(\phi), \rho_W(\phi)$ respectively.

I would like to know if
$$\dim_k \Hom_G(V, W) = \# \{ (i, j)   :   a_i = b_j \}$$

I know that $\dim_k \Hom_G(V, W) = \langle \chi_V, \chi_W \rangle$, and that $f \in \Hom_G(V, W)$ iff $f \circ \rho_V(\phi) = \rho_W(\phi) \circ f$. But I don't know how to proceed from there.

(NB: already asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4355067/) two weeks ago, with no success).

Comment: This is (16.22) Lemma (ii) in Geer--Moonen--Edixhoven's book project on Abelian Varieties.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If $k$ is of characteristic zero or characteristic $p$ and $G$ is a pro-$p'$-group, then yes. In that case, everything in sight is semisimple by Maschke's theorem, the eigenvalues $a_i$ and $b_j$ give you the decomposition into irreducibles, and every pair of equal eigenvalues contributes one degree of freedom by Schur's lemma.

Otherwise no, even in the simplest case, because of lack of semiplicity. If $k=\overline{\mathbb{F}_p}$, $G=C_p$, $\rho_V(\phi) = \begin{pmatrix}1&1\\&1\end{pmatrix}$ and $\rho_W(\phi)=\begin{pmatrix}1&\\&1\end{pmatrix}$, then $a_1=a_2=b_1=b_2$ so that your conjecture would predict $\dim_k \operatorname{Hom}_G(V,W) = 4$, but it is only 2, because $V$ is not semi simple, but $W$ is, and therefore every morphism must factor through $V/\operatorname{rad}(V)$.

Comment: Doesn't the question demand V,W be semisimple?

Comment: You are right. Then, we're in the first case again.

Comment: Thank you very much. May I ask how exactly the eigenvalues  give a decomposition of $V$ into irreps? The $a_i$'s might not be all distinct a priori. (Sorry if this is a silly question, I am not very familiar with representation theory...). This has probably to do with the group being (pro)-cyclic?

Comment: If $V$ decomposes as a sum of irreducibles $V_i$, then the characteristic polynomial of $\rho_V(\phi)$ is the product of the characteristic polynomials $\rho_{V_i}(\phi)$. Since $G$ is abelian, all irreducible representations are 1-dimensional, therefore each irreducible $V_i$ gives you one eigenvalue $a_i$. Conversely, since $G$ is cyclic, the character of $V_i$ is completely defined by $a_i$ (the values are powers of it) hence $V_i$ is determined as well.

Comment: So knowing the $a_i$ which appear in the characteristic polynomial $\rho_V(\phi)$ completely determines the decomposition into irreducibles. The formula for the dimension of $Hom_G$ now follows from Schurs Lemma. (And I hope the same reasoning goes through for the continuous case as well)

Comment: @GeorgLehner : thanks, I forgot that irreps of an abelian group are 1-dimensional... (it should also be true for infinite abelian groups, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/354926, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur's_lemma#Statement_and_Proof_of_the_Lemma)